# How do I stop dashcast from deleting segments in live mode?

Tags: mpeg-dash, dashcast

I am using dashcast to convert a UDP stream to MPEG-DASH in live mode, like this:

```
dashcast -v "udp://@localhost:1234?fifo_size=100000" -live
```

It seems that in live mode, dashcast deletes older segments, and only retains the most recent ones (presumably just enough for a player to satisfy the minimum buffer time). Is there some way I can force dashcast NOT to delete segment files as it goes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `-time-shift -1`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13900239)

Comment: Why do you think it does not answer the question?